# Realize a group by from a model having multiple foreign keys to the the same column of another table

Tags: django, postgresql, aggregation

following situation

```
ModelA(django.db.models.Model):
  abc = ForeignKey('modelB', related_name="from abc")
  def = ForeignKey('modelB', related_name="from def")

modelB(django.db.models.Model):
```

Is there a way to achieve a `GROUP_BY` via `ModelA.objects.values('some_magic_link_to_Model_B').annotate()` instead of `ModelA.objects.values('abc', 'def').annotate()` (with the consequence to manually construct the result list because it results in grouped results of two keys) or do i have to consider adding a intermediate M2M transition?

Comment: As you suggest you should use an m2m.

Comment: Yes, that would obviously be better but my question was if there maybe is a possible workaround i'm not aware of without sprawling side effects(e.g. performance issues), i found a for me okayish way now, see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Okay, since i have a fixed `modelB` instance i want to aggregate, i found a solution.

```
    identifier_pk=django.db.models.Value(fixedInstanceOfmodelB__modelC.pk, output_field=IntegerField())
    stats = ctx.order_by().annotate(
        group_key=identifier_pk,
    ).values('group_key').annotate(
        whatever=asd,
    )
```

but that just the specific case where i only want to get aggregated stats for a single instance of `modelB`, is there a generic way to get a `GROUP_BY` with a single key e.g. `modelB.pk`